# Identifying an app from a URL request

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

If a URL request is made from an iPhone app, is it possible for the service to which the request is made to identify the app? Generally, a service can see the IP address from which the request is made, but is more identifying information included in the request? My aim is to ensure that the app cannot be identified.

Comment: Have you looked at the HTTP Headers yet?  There are a lot of headers with each request.  Have you read this?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields Specifically, have you looked at the User Agent header?

Comment: I have not will give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: I tried this, but the "allHTTPHeaderFields" returns an empty dict.

Comment: @CastToInteger: First.  That's a separate question.  Second.  And more important.  You have to get the HTTP headers on the server, where the service is implemented.  What is this "allHTTPHeaderFields"?  What framework are you using on the server?  What language is your server written in?

Comment: This is an iPhone question, as the tag states. I don't want any server to be able to identify the app.

Comment: "it possible for the service to which the request is made to identify the app?" is a server-side question.  The answer is Yes.  It's in the HTTP headers.  Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log the simulator network traffic to a file:

```
sudo tcpdump -s 0 -A -i en0 port 80 > log.txt
```

Then read the file and see if your app behaves any different from a browser. Note that your network interface may vary. Run `ifconfig -a` to see if you are on en0, en1, or what.

You can change the user agent and any other header if you need to...

- If you are using [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/):
  `[ASIHTTPRequest setDefaultUserAgentString:@"firefox blah blah"];`
- If you are using NSMutableURLRequest:
  `[request setValue:@"firefox blah" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];`

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. I see the app name is being transmitted by iOS in the UserAgent field. I suppose there wont be any way to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a parameter from the app to the service. `http://..url?param1=..&app=myApp`

Comment: Your answer does the exact opposite of what I am trying to achieve.